# Replace XML node

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table in which there is a column named "ServiceConfig" with datatype xml.

I have a record with xml like below :

```
<Config>
  <services>
    <service name="pro" />
    <service name="postdata" />
  </services>
</Config>
```

Now, I want to replace `<service name="pro" />` with `<service name="pro" username="u" password="p"/>`. So the resultant XML will be

```
<Config>
  <services>
    <service name="pro" username="u" password="p"/>
    <service name="postdata" />
  </services>
</Config>
```

How do I achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to add the new attributes like this...

```
DECLARE @xmltest TABLE (ServiceConfig XML)
DECLARE @username VARCHAR(15) = 'u'
DECLARE @password VARCHAR(15) = 'p'
DECLARE @xml xml

INSERT @xmlTest values ('<Config>
                           <services>
                             <service name="pro" />
                             <service name="postdata" />
                           </services>
                         </Config>')

SELECT @xml = ServiceConfig from @xmltest

SET @xml.modify('insert (attribute username {sql:variable("@username")}, 
                         attribute password {sql:variable("@password")}) 
                         as last into (/Config/services/service)[1]')

UPDATE @xmltest SET ServiceConfig = @xml

SELECT * FROM @xmltest
```

[Click here to go to SQL Fiddle demo of above code](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/13930).